# How to add output from a command to a group name in a script?

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I'm manually creating a version of useradd, and at the moment what i'm trying to do is get the output of this command:

```
head -$1 /folder/file | grep $2 | cut -d ',' -f4
```

and input it into this command:

```
echo "$1:x:50$int" >> /etc/group
```

where $1 is. Basically the first command is pulling a companies name and I want to add it to a group. I already have a group id setup.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the user group `$1` exists already? Adding a duplicate entry in `/etc/group` may have unexpected and weird results.

Comment: @DavidFoerster i want to replace $1 with the output of the first command. Assume its a brand new entry, i'm creating new users from scratch.

Comment: Wouldn't this work?  `echo "$(head -$1 /folder/file | grep $2 | cut -d ',' -f4):x:50$int" >> /etc/group`

Comment: @Terrance: Could you please post this as a proper answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since all that you are trying to do is to get the output of the first command into the second command, you can do it with running a command substitution `$()` of the first command into the second command.  To combine these together put the first command into the second command where you want the output to be so that you don't have the need of assigning the output of the first command into a variable then putting into the second command.

First command:

```
head -$1 /folder/file | grep $2 | cut -d ',' -f4
```

That you know returns what you want.  In your second command you know that you want the output of the first command in a specific location like where the `$1` is located in the second command.

Second command:

```
echo "$1:x:50$int" >> /etc/group
```

Since `$1` is what you want to replace in the second command, you would then replace the `$1` with the command substitution and command of the first one like this:

```
echo "$(head -$1 /folder/file | grep $2 | cut -d ',' -f4):x:50$int" >> /etc/group
```

Hope this helps!